# Failing at NetBeans Java Native Packaging for Linux

Tags: netbeans

Doing Linux Native Package builds I'm running into problems with both RPM and DEB.  In the case of RPMs, it's saying that rpmbuild cannot be found.  Then for DEBs it reports the dpkg cannot be found.

Both dpkg and rpmbuild are installed and are in /usr/bin.  Both are in my path and execute fine from CLI.  Failure is the same whether I start NetBeans from GUI or CLI.  I've even symlinked rpmbuild and dpkg into my NetBeans bin directory.  No luck.

How does one go about getting NetBeans to find dpkg and rpmbuild so that it can complete native builds from the GUI?  Currently working with SuSE LEAP 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the "Package All Artifacts" option is currently generating .deb and .rpms, but I can't generate them individually.  I'm OK with this.  I think the most likely change to make that option work was symlinking the binaries from user bin into my netbeans bin.